# Qgis2leaf doesn't show layers with scale-dependent visibility

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2leaf

When I add layers to the QGIS2LEAF dialog box it accepts it and opens up the preview in my web browser, but when I starting looking for the layers, in this case points for campgrounds, I dont see any of them. I have them on a 1:145,000 Scale Dependent Visibility minimum and 1:1 Maxium, but when I zoom in to where they should appear I dont see anything. Feel Free to ask for more information, I will add a couple photos the way I have it set up

[image: Scale Level]

[image: QGIS2LEAF]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is true.

QGIS2leaf does not support "Scale Dependent Visibility"!

QGIS2leaf was developed to extract a qgis project into a leaflet based webmap. It is not designed to "transfer" all qgis possibilities into styling/behaviour of leaflet. It can build the basis for great webmaps but will definitely require you to do some manual coding in the index.html...

Feel free to open an issue at the [qgis2leaf issue tracker](https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf/issues) at github or check out [qgis2web](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2web/) which is qgis2leaf and qgis2openlayers in one plugin. @Tom Chadwin is the maintainer of qgis2web.

Comment: Okay, thanks!!! Just wondering if I was doing something wrong, and for the coding part I dont know a whole lot of coding, very very basic, just to recognize a couple things, but I will try and find someone to help! Thanks a lot man!!!!

Comment: write a mail to info@geolicious.de if you need professional help or try on javascript FAQs and the leaflet API section to find suitable help.

Answer (score 1):

I just released qgis2web 0.16.0 which supports scale-dependent visibility in Leaflet output. That should do the job for you.